# Quarkus do not find old methods signatures of external libraries

Tags: java, reactive-programming, quarkus, gradlew, quarkus-rest-client

I am developing a `Quarkus` application, using my own external library ([download from maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.github.trikorasolns/keycloak-quarkus-client), [see the code on gitHub](https://github.com/trikorasolns/keycloak-quarkus-client/)).

When upgrading from version `0.0.6` to the `0.0.7`, I had modified the signature of the method `addRolesToGroup` and after updating the dependencies of the main project, Quarkus is still looking for the old signatures of the method, thus, I get the following exception:

```
 : java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.trikorasolutions.keycloak.client.clientresource.KeycloakAuthAdminResource$$QuarkusRestClientInterfaceCreator.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.ClientProxies.get(ClientProxies.java:36)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.WebTargetImpl.proxy(WebTargetImpl.java:390)
        at io.quarkus.rest.client.reactive.runtime.RestClientBuilderImpl.build(RestClientBuilderImpl.java:328)
        at io.quarkus.rest.client.reactive.runtime.RestClientCDIDelegateBuilder.build(RestClientCDIDelegateBuilder.java:75)
        at io.quarkus.rest.client.reactive.runtime.RestClientCDIDelegateBuilder.build(RestClientCDIDelegateBuilder.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.rest.client.reactive.runtime.RestClientCDIDelegateBuilder.createDelegate(RestClientCDIDelegateBuilder.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.rest.client.reactive.runtime.RestClientReactiveCDIWrapperBase.<init>(RestClientReactiveCDIWrapperBase.java:20)
        at com.trikorasolutions.keycloak.client.clientresource.KeycloakAuthAdminResource$$CDIWrapper.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.trikorasolutions.keycloak.client.clientresource.KeycloakAuthAdminResource$$CDIWrapper_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
        at com.trikorasolutions.keycloak.client.clientresource.KeycloakAuthAdminResource$$CDIWrapper_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at com.trikorasolutions.keycloak.client.clientresource.KeycloakAuthAdminResource$$CDIWrapper_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.trikorasolutions.keycloak.client.clientresource.KeycloakAuthAdminResource$$CDIWrapper_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.trikorasolutions.keycloak.client.bl.KeycloakClientLogic_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
        at com.trikorasolutions.keycloak.client.bl.KeycloakClientLogic_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getApplicationScopedDelegate(ClientProxies.java:18)
        at com.trikorasolutions.keycloak.client.bl.KeycloakClientLogic_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(Unknown Source)
        at com.trikorasolutions.keycloak.client.bl.KeycloakClientLogic_ClientProxy.getTokenForUser(Unknown Source)
        at com.trikorasolutions.itsm.bl.user.KeycloakBl.getBackendServiceToken(KeycloakBl.java:62)
        at com.trikorasolutions.itsm.bl.user.KeycloakBl.createUser(KeycloakBl.java:71)
        at com.trikorasolutions.itsm.bl.user.KeycloakBl_ClientProxy.createUser(Unknown Source)
        at com.trikorasolutions.itsm.test.demo.CreateDemoTest.createDemo(CreateDemoTest.java:235)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.runExtensionMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:995)
        at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:815)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.testing.JunitTestRunner$3.run(JunitTestRunner.java:229)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.testing.ModuleTestRunner$2.run(ModuleTestRunner.java:90)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.testing.TestSupport.runInternal(TestSupport.java:396)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.testing.TestSupport$2.run(TestSupport.java:304)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.trikorasolutions.keycloak.client.clientresource.KeycloakAuthAdminResource.addRolesToGroup(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, [Lcom.trikorasolutions.keycloak.client.dto.RoleRepresentation;)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2108)
        at com.trikorasolutions.keycloak.client.clientresource.KeycloakAuthAdminResource$$QuarkusRestClientInterface.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        ... 104 more
```

**Signature in version 0.0.6:**

```
  @POST
  @Path("/realms/{realm}/groups/{id}/role-mappings/realm")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  Uni<JsonArray> addRolesToGroup(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String bearerToken,
      @PathParam("realm") String realm, @QueryParam("grant_type") String grantType,
      @QueryParam("client_id") String clientId, @PathParam("id") String groupId,
      RoleRepresentation[] roles);
```

**Signature in version 0.0.7:**

```
  @POST
  @Path("/realms/{realm}/groups/{id}/role-mappings/realm")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  Uni<JsonArray> addRolesToGroup(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String bearerToken,
      @PathParam("realm") String realm, @QueryParam("grant_type") String grantType,
      @QueryParam("client_id") String clientId, @PathParam("id") String groupId,
      String roles);
```

I reach this problem on the first use of my library. When initializing the CDI.

Do you know any way of clearing that cache of Quarkus, so it will only take into account the new versions of the signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, the Jandex indexes of both versions of your `keycloak-quarkus-client` library have been generated on June 24th at 12:15. So my guess is that the Jandex index wasn't properly rebuilt and you still have the old one in the jar.

That would have to be fixed in your publication workflow.

Comment: You are correct, there was a problem in the release of the project, so some of the modules did not compile properly.